# tax band in different salary javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

The function result should print the following: Simple javascript function to calculate tax

Input your age and click the button

Comment: What on earth is your question?

Comment: The values in your if statements are nothing like the ones in the question, though.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: current behavior => awaited behavior

Comment: Sorry I think I got you guys confused with the code and my questions . I simply want print out the growth , Net , Total including the tax sum .

Comment: I don't know quite what you mean by "print out" here.  But I assume standard DOM manipulations will take care of it for you.  (Don't forget to convert input strings with `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, or the `Number` constructor!)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```js
const brackets = [
  {min: 0, max: 10000, rate: 0},
  {min: 10000, max: 35000, rate: .2},
  {min: 35000, max: 100000, rate: .4},
  {min: 100000, rate: .5}
]

const calc = brackets => income => brackets.map(
  bracket => (
    Math.min(income, bracket.max || Infinity) - 
    Math.min(income, bracket.min)
  ) * bracket.rate
).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const taxes2017 = calc(brackets)

console.log(taxes2017(73500)) //~> 20400
console.log(taxes2017(156300)) //~> 59150
```

This allows you to more declaratively list the tax table and/or create different tax calculators based on different tables.  Obviously, if you wanted the percentages in your input rather than the numeric fractions, you could do this by adding a `/ 100` in the rate calculation.

Comment: Thanks Scott I like your Idea , how can I add a input field in html when I type £35000 for example when i click on the calculate button the result should be something like :-

Comment: your salary tax is = £ the tax amount

Comment: you take home : = £ the Net salary  many thanks for your time

Comment: If that's what you want here, I would suggest asking another question with a simplified version of what you're looking for.  I think people assumed this was about the tax calculation, since most JS users find plain DOM manipulation easier than even slightly complex calculations.

Answer (score -1):

1- £0 to £10k is taxed at 0%

2- £10,001 to £35k is taxed at 20%

3- £35,001 to £100,000 is taxed at 40%

4- £100k plus is taxed at 50%

```
let income = 75000;
incomeTax = calculateTax(income);

function calculateTax(income) {

   let tax = 0;

   if (income > 100000) {
      tax = .2 * (35000 - 10001) + .4 * (100000 - 35001) + .5 * (income - 100001);
   } else if (income > 35000) {
      tax = .2 * (35000 - 10001) + .4 * (income - 35001);
   } else if (income > 10000) {
      tax = .2 * (income - 10001);
   } 

   return tax;
}
```